# Interactive Calculator Using Custom Exception handling

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am trying to build an interactive calculator in python. The only issue I am having is with dealing with the custom errors.

I have constructed 3 custom errors in order to let the user know the issue for each invalid input:

- `FormulaError` should be raised when a user enters an unallowed mathematical operator. I want to allow the user to re-enter a character until a proper operator is chosen
- `MissingElement` should be raised when a user enters more or less than three number/operator characters. I want to allow the user to re-enter characters until the amount of number/operator characters are equals 3. (ex: entering `2 + 3` counts as 3 elements)
- `ValueError` should be raised when a user enters a non-numerical value to the calculator. I want to allow the user to re-enter characters until they choose proper numbers.

See below:

```
class Error(Exception): pass
class FormulaError(Exception): pass
class MissingElement(Exception): pass
class ValueError(Exception): pass

def parse_input(user_input):
  input_list = user_input.split()
  try:
    if len(input_list) != 3:
        raise MissingElement
  except MissingElement:
    print('Invalid number of elements.')
    print()
  n1, op, n2 = input_list
  try:
    n1 = float(n1)
    n2 = float(n2)
  except ValueError:
    print('The first and third input value must be numbers.')
  return n1, op, n2

def calculate(n1, op, n2):
  if op == '+':
    return n1 + n2
  if op == '-':
    return n1 - n2
  if op == '*':
    return n1 * n2
  if op == '/':
    return n1 / n2
  else:
    return FormulaError(f'{op} is not a valid operator')

while True:
  user_input = input('>>> ')
  if user_input == 'quit':
    break
  n1, op, n2 = parse_input(user_input)
  result = calculate(n1, op, n2)
  print(result)
```

`FormulaError` works as it should, but the other two do not. I'm working on fixing the custom exception handling in the `parse_input` function, specifically `ValueError`.

When my (invalid) input is `2 + a`, the traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\darks\OneDrive\Documents\7\HW3\calculator.py", line 43, in <module>
    n1, op, n2 = parse_input(user_input)
  File "c:\Users\darks\OneDrive\Documents\7\HW3\calculator.py", line 18, in parse_input
    n1 = float(n1)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

I want the traceback to print my custom message:

```
"The first and third input value must be numbers."
```

How can I fix the error handling?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) class defined in the Python built-in exceptions. You're trying to define a custom exception class with the same name.

If you rename your class something else (e.g. `MyValueError`) but change nothing else, you'll still find that when you're trying to raise MyValueError with intentional inputs (e.g. `b - a`) the error that gets raised in traceback is still the built-in ValueError because that is the error Python is encountering (`float(b)`).

If your objective is to use your custom exception `MyValueError` to accomplish the same task that the built-in exception `ValueError` normally accomplishes, consider this:

- You used a `try` block and conditional statements to implement your `MissingElement` exception.
- You used conditional statements to implement your `FormulaError` exception.

Consider whether or not it's possible to use a similar approach for your custom exception version of `ValueError`.

If your goal is to ask users for permissible inputs repeatedly, you should consider implementing a while loop, but that's a more complicated endeavor that likely goes beyond the scope of this question (and may constitute unfair assistance on your "HW3").

Comment: is there a way to make the custom error focus on the specific 'float(a)' and 'float(b)', kind of like the same way I did in the 'calculate()' function ? In the 'calculate()' function, if I used a wrong operator input, then it would just ask me again.

Comment: Yes, there are ways (more than one) to implement a custom exception that handles behavior that would normally raise a built-in `ValueError` exception; see above.